# 'BooleanField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute' in django

Tags: python, django, forms

as the title says i am getting the error while i am using a booleanfield:

'BooleanField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute' in django

Models.py

```
class contactData(models.Model):

    ...
    mapActivated         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = contactData
    fields = [
        'vision',
        'horario',
        'image_path',
        'mapActivated',
        ]
    labels = {
        'image_path': '',    
    }

    widgets = {
        'mapActivated': forms.BooleanField(required=True)
    }
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing form *fields* with form *widgets*. A [**`forms.BooleanField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield) is *not* a widget, it is a form field. A widget is for example the [**`CheckboxInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxInput), it specifies how to render that in a HTML form.

You can specify the field as:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mapActivated = forms.BooleanField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = contactData
        fields = [
            'vision',
            'horario',
            'image_path',
            'mapActivated',
        ]
        labels = {
            'image_path': '',    
        }
```

By setting this as `required=True`, you require that the user will check the checkbox. This might not be (per se) what you want to do. If the user has the freedom to check/uncheck it. Removing `required=True` should be sufficient.